# perl: script to find valid/active pids of tomcat and stop them

Tags: arrays, perl, cmd

updated:

I have the below perl program to stop tomcat, check if its still running , and kill if it is running.

1)When I execute the cmd `ps -ef | grep /opt/accurev/WebUI/tomcat | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | awk '{print $2}'` outside the script, its returning me single process id `27640` , but  inside the script The output of the array is printing as 2 pids, out of which one is not a valid/inactive process. How can I make my script return only the valid pids?

2)My 1st cmd to stop the tomcat is also not running inside the script `/opt/app/WebUI/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh`

What am I missing here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#Shutdown the Tomcat
print "Shutting down tomcat\n";
`/opt/app/WebUI/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh`;

#Check if there are any instances of Tomcat still running, and if yes kill them
my @pid = `ps -ef | grep /opt/app/WebUI/tomcat | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | awk '{print \$2}'`;
my $pid;
foreach $pid (@pid) {
  print "$pid\n";
 }
if (@pid) { # @pid is not empty
  print "Tomcat is still running. Killing them now \n";
  foreach $pid (@pid) {
    print "Killing the tomcat instance with pid : $pid\n";
   `kill -9 $pid`;
  }
} else { # @pid is empty
   print "Tomcat is not running \n";
}
```

Current Output:

```
 -bash-4.1$ ps -ef | grep /opt/app/WebUI/tomcat | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | awk '{print $2}'
 27640

-bash-4.1$ perl  daily_backup.pl 
Shutting down tomcat
27640

27777

Tomcat is still running. Killing them now 
Killing the tomcat instance with pid : 27640


Killing the tomcat instance with pid : 27777

kill 27777: No such process
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the dollar sign in the backticks?

```
my @pid = `ps -ef | grep /opt/app/WebUI/tomcat | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | awk '{print \$2}'`;
```

Comment: It worked a bit after adding the escape char, but still not sure why the 1st cmd to stop tomcat is not working.And also the `ps -ef` command is returning one pid when we ran outside the script and its returning two pids inside the script.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the current output as well